# Bootstrap button bug

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to bootstrap and I watched some tutorials (ASP.NET).

I created a button with a CssClass:

But the button looks bugged? It must look like the first button, but my button is the second:

[image]

I have no clue what I am doing wrong!

This is my container:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span2">...</div>
        <div class="span8">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </div>
        <div class="span2">
            <asp:Button ID="btnSignup" runat="server" Text="Button" CssClass="btn btn-large btn-success" />
        </div>
    </div>
  <h1>Bootstrap starter template</h1>
  <p>Use this document as a way to quick start any new project.<br/> All you get is this message and a barebones HTML document.</p>

</div>
```

Comment: Sorry! Going to do it now!

Comment: Which tutorials you watched can you post link here? with your code

Comment: <asp:Button ID="btnSignup" runat="server" Text="Button" CssClass="btn btn-large btn-success" /> is correct. Your css calls are correct. You will have to provide the whole html-css-javascript context if you need more help.

Comment: Related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17104094/asp-net-button-component-doesnt-work-under-twitter-bootstrap-theme  and  https://www.google.ca/#sclient=psy-ab&q=bootstrap+button+with+asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer!

I downloaded the customized bootstrap files with full features via this link:

http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/customize.html

Then I am getting that bug.

But when I download bootstrap from below, and replace the css file from the customized bootstrap with the new downloaded css:

http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/

Then I don't have any bugs!

Comment: Interesting. In that case it's possible that one of the colour variables in the customised version is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Did you modify Bootstrap CSS in any way or are you loading any additional CSS?

What browser are you seeing this in?

It would help if you posted your code on [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net)

Anyway, this issue happens when you remove `background-image` from the normal (mouse out) button state of the `.btn-success` class. Bootstrap uses transition to shift background-position by 15px in hover state and this is what you end up with.

Comment: I only changed the background of the Body {} and I am not loading any additional CSS... I see this in Chrome, and in IE it works better (Green color) but in IE the button border is not rounded.

Answer (score 0):

Just to complement your own answer, since you are using bootstrap + Visual Studio, you may have to know that there's a bug on Visual Studio that edits some CSS3 properties.
You should keep an backup from bootstrap.css, because this issue may happen again when editing an .aspx, .htm that uses this stylesheet.
I just know the bug, but I don't have any solutions for it